# Guacamole ldap 1.3.0 linux native installation

Tags: linux, ldap, native, guacamole

I have done guacamole-1.3.0 version native installation in my linux centOs machine.
I need to do LDAP guacamole integration but I am facing some difficulty in doing the configuration.
I have created /etc/guacamole/extension and added ldap-auth 1.3.0 jar inside /etc/guacamole/extensions. Used Tomcat and that is running in the server. Started guacd service. Installation is done but ldap integration facing difficulty.
Need help on how to check and login using ldap auth.

Kindly help me with the steps for ldap guacamole integration for version-1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Here the guacamole LDAP Properties vim /etc/guacamole/guacamole.properties

```
# Auth provider class auth-provider:net.sourceforge.guacamole.net.auth.ldap.LDAPAuthenticationProvider 
   #LDAP Properties
    ldap-hostname: stackoverflow.local 
    ldap-port: 636 or 3268(LDAP Unsecure conncetion) 
    ldap-user-base-dn:CN=Users,DC=stackoverflow,DC=local
    ldap-user-base-dn: dc=stackoverflow,dc=local
    ldap-search-bind-dn:cn=ldap1,CN=Users,dc=stackoverflow,dc=local
    ldap-search-bind-password: XXXXXXXXXXX  (Password for ldap1 user)
    ldap-username-attribute: sAMAccountName
    ldap-user-search-filter:(objectClass=user)(!(objectCategory=computer))
    ldap-max-search-results:4000 
    mysql-auto-create-accounts: true
    ldap-follow-referrals:true
```

Then restart tomcat gucad and mysql service

```
systemctl restart tomcat mysqld guacd
```

login with domain user simply by giving domain name and password in guacamole dashboard.

If you need more help reply back here with logs i can helpout